# Probability of getting a hand with at least 6 doubles in domino

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I have this problem:

Domino has 28 tiles with 7 doubles. Each hand has 7 tiles. What is the probability of getting a hand with at least 6 doubles?

Since it's an "at least" kind of problem I did the following:

Total number of hands: $28C7$

$P(hand\  with\  at \ least \ 6 \ doubles) = 1 - P(no \ double ) - P(one \ double )- P(two \ doubles )-\dots - P(six \ doubles ) = 1- \bigg( \frac{(7C0\ \times \ 21C7)+ (7C1\ \times \ 21C6) + (7C2\ \times \ 21C5) + (7C3\ \times \ 21C4) + (7C4\ \times \ 21C3) + (7C5\ \times \ 21C1) + (7C6\ \times \ 21C1) }{28C7} \bigg)$

This gives me a probability of $0.8035$ but I'm doubtful if my approach was correct. Is it right or is there another way of solving this?

Thanks.

Comment: You wrote on the left "hand *with six* doubles" as opposed to "hand *with at least six* doubles."  This could be mistaken for you meaning getting exactly six.  Then... in your workings, you subtracted P(six doubles)...  You wanted to include getting six doubles in your count since "at least six" means "greater than or equal to six"... not strictly more than six so you shouldn't have subtracted this.

Comment: That all said... you wound up doing far more arithmetic and writing than is necessary.  At least six in this case is just *exactly six* or *exactly seven*... only two events to consider.  Add these two probabilities together rather than going the roundabout way of subtracting the other five events away from $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit the "hand with 6" part. Apart from that, yes I went the wrong way. You're right, it ends up being: $P(hand \ with \ at \ least \ six \ doubles) = \frac{7C6 \times 21C1 + 7C7}{28C7}$

Comment: You can also keep from writing the C1 and such when the numbers are so close to the boundaries... 7C6 = 7 for instance so this could have been written even more cleanly as $\dfrac{7\times 21 + 1}{\binom{28}{7}}$.  Of course, it helps to write them if you want to reinforce where the numbers came from logically, but its not strictly necessary here.

Comment: I'll take note. Thanks.